# How do I group a data frame by multiple columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have an incredibly complex data frame, which looks something like this when organized into a data frame:

```
HEADER
<chr>
13:30:00.587: <- $GPGGA,183000.30,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.5,M,-33.4,M,,*68 
13:30:00.683: <- $GPGLL,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,183000.40,A,A*72   
13:30:00.779: <- $GPVTG,159.6,T,163.2,M,0.1,N,0.1,K,A*2E    
13:30:00.827: <- $HCHDG,74.8,0.0,E,3.6,W*6E 
13:30:01.003: <- $WIMDA,29.9641,I,1.0147,B,26.5,C,,,48.2,,14.6,C,323.0,T,326.6,M,1.4,N,0.7,M*66 
13:30:01.051: <- $WIMWV,248.4,R,1.1,N,A*29  
13:30:01.114: <- $WIMWV,255.6,T,1.3,N,A*23  
13:30:01.195: <- $YXXDR,A,-53.9,D,PTCH,A,-34.2,D,ROLL*57    
13:30:01.307: <- $YXXDR,A,0.571,G,XACC,A,0.783,G,YACC,A,-0.181,G,ZACC*57    
13:30:01.578: <- $GPGGA,183001.30,4415.6242,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.9,M,-33.4,M,,*64
```

I need to organize it such that I am able to group_by the 5-letter string at the beginning, like GPGGA, which I have managed to do using this code:

```
df <- data.frame(Weather_data)
df_GPGGA <- df %>%
  mutate("Entry" = gsub(".*\\$([A-Z]+),.*", "\\1", HEADER)) %>%
  group_by("Entry") %>%
  filter(Entry == "GPGGA")
```

as this outputs a 2-column df with all of the data in one long string like above as the column "HEADER" which is an ok title for now, along with a second column "Entry" grouped by the exact 5-letter character string in the specific line (see screencap below).

My ultimate goal is to be able to make a .csv for each separate data set (separated by the 5-letter string, hence my use of filter; I have repeated this code for each different 5-letter string. The outputs for each line of GPGGA code the instrument I am working with are not all of the same information as the outputs for a GPGLL line, for example) with each comma-separated value in its designated column. But I have no idea how to format each document from there. Here's a screencap of one attempt: [.csv without data separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZcng.png). How do I get all of this data into separate columns?

Here's the requested reproducible data set:

dput(Weather_data) outputs [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMPD5.png)

Comment: Hello!  Kindly provide a reproducible dataset, by pasting the output of `dput(Weather_data)` in your post.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW: missing `%>%` after `group_by(.)`, and your `filter` should have `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: I've added the dput(Weather_data) output and corrected my code errors; I'd missed them copying the text over, they were in my original code.

Comment: The whole point of using `dpit(x)` is so that we can copy the *text* to have an unambiguous sample of data. An image of it is not very useful. Having said that, is it any different than the doubt output I included in my answer? Does my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

```r
library(dplyr)
stuff <- strcapture("^([0-9.:]*): <-\\s*(\\$[^,]+),(.*)", dat$HEADER,
           list(time = "", group = "", string = "")) %>%
  transmute(group, string = paste0(time, ",", string)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(data = lapply(paste(string, collapse = "\n"),
                          function(z) read.csv(text = z, header = FALSE)))
stuff
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#   group  data              
#   <chr>  <list>            
# 1 $GPGGA <df[,15] [2 x 15]>
# 2 $GPGLL <df[,8] [1 x 8]>  
# 3 $GPVTG <df[,10] [1 x 10]>
# 4 $HCHDG <df[,6] [1 x 6]>  
# 5 $WIMDA <df[,21] [1 x 21]>
# 6 $WIMWV <df[,6] [2 x 6]>  
# 7 $YXXDR <df[,13] [2 x 13]>
stuff$data[[1]]
#             V1       V2       V3 V4       V5 V6 V7 V8  V9   V10 V11   V12 V13 V14  V15
# 1 13:30:00.587 183000.3 4415.624  N 8823.977  W  1  7 1.7 225.5   M -33.4   M  NA *68 
# 2 13:30:01.578 183001.3 4415.624  N 8823.977  W  1  7 1.7 225.9   M -33.4   M  NA  *64
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(HEADER = c("13:30:00.587: <- $GPGGA,183000.30,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.5,M,-33.4,M,,*68 ", "13:30:00.683: <- $GPGLL,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,183000.40,A,A*72   ", "13:30:00.779: <- $GPVTG,159.6,T,163.2,M,0.1,N,0.1,K,A*2E    ", "13:30:00.827: <- $HCHDG,74.8,0.0,E,3.6,W*6E ", "13:30:01.003: <- $WIMDA,29.9641,I,1.0147,B,26.5,C,,,48.2,,14.6,C,323.0,T,326.6,M,1.4,N,0.7,M*66 ", "13:30:01.051: <- $WIMWV,248.4,R,1.1,N,A*29  ", "13:30:01.114: <- $WIMWV,255.6,T,1.3,N,A*23  ", "13:30:01.195: <- $YXXDR,A,-53.9,D,PTCH,A,-34.2,D,ROLL*57    ", "13:30:01.307: <- $YXXDR,A,0.571,G,XACC,A,0.783,G,YACC,A,-0.181,G,ZACC*57    ", "13:30:01.578: <- $GPGGA,183001.30,4415.6242,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.9,M,-33.4,M,,*64")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```